# IOS/Objective-C: NSArray randomization issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this array with strings and I want to randomize it and display the output in a label. But with this code I'm having always the same strange output which is "2"...Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.quoteInput.delegate=self;
    self.quoteLabel=_quotationLabel;
    self.correctLabel.alpha=0;
    self.wrongLabel.alpha=0;
    
    _quoteInput.delegate=self;
    
    
    
   _levelOne = @[
                   [words Quotes:@"First Quote."],
                   [words Quotes:@"Second Quote."],
                 [words Quotes:@"And so on."]];
    
}

-(void)randomQuotes{

    for (NSInteger x = 0; x < [_levelOne count]; x++) {

        NSInteger randInt = arc4random() % ([_levelOne count] - x) + x;
        [_levelOne objectAtIndex:randInt];

        NSString *one = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", randInt];
        self.quoteLabel.text = one;
    }
}
- (IBAction)generateQuote:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self randomQuotes];
}
```

EDIT
The words class:

```
 + (instancetype)Quotes:(NSString *)quotes
                       {
        

return [[words alloc] initWithQuotes:quotes];
}
```

Comment: What is the desired output?  "First Quote" or "Second Quote" or "Third Quote"?  Or a random set of characters from those strings?

Comment: i want the output to be a random string like "First quote"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you can explain what `[word Quotes:]` method does, it should be much simpler than what you are trying to do.

```
_levelOne = @[@"First Quote.", "Second Quote.", @"And so on."];

-(void) randomQuotes{ 
    NSInteger randInt = arc4random_uniform( [_levelOne count] );
    self.quoteLabel.text = [_levelOne objectAtIndex:randInt];
}
```

Comment: its crashing with the log: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2094589961 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'